# Keeping data layer as separate deployments

Tags: architecture, cloud, microservices

Is there a name for this architectural style in which data is stripped out of a service into separate deployments? Or does it resemble something?

1. Every bounded context is composed of UI, one or several business services (BS) and one or several internal data providers (DP).
2. BS are stateless and are not allowed to store data anywhere else than via REST API exposed by their DP. They must not "talk" to any other service.
3. DP can use namespaces in databases running in a corporate cloud (for instance keyspace in Cassandra).
4. DP may talk to external services (outside bounded context) through their gateways.

I can see lots of problems in here and not that many benefits. Could you provide your non-biased opinion on this?

[image: Architecture]

Answer (score 1):

We currently have a similar architecture that we run today at my organization. It is not quite as flexible as the one you are proposing, but strongly separating the business logic services from data/domain services has been very successful over a long period of time.  I don't know if there is a formal architectural name for it, but it definitely allowed a stable domain to be reused in lots of different applications.

I know this doesn't perfectly answer your question, but it is an example of a successful architecture that closely approximates your proposed one.

Comment: But is it really worth the tradeoff? I mean increased complexity (additional deployments), adding to response times, another point of failure, additional problems with consistency and probably much more? What if the UI cannot hit that CRUD app directly but rather than that has to go through the middleman service even for GET operations? Lot's of boilerplate code or some automating "magical" proxying?

Comment: I certainly can't tel you whether or not it's worth it,  I don't know your business or technology constraints.  IN GENERAL it is valuable to separate your business logic from your data access logic.

Comment: Yeah but generally speaking, if it is so beneficial why it is pretty unusual in the microservice world? I mean every resource there is states that the microservice just owns its schema/database, no one mentions that rule.

Comment: Strongly separating the business logic from the data services I believe is the core of building a good data warehouse.

Comment: @kboom, agreed, it is not common.  In general microservices own their own data model.  There would need to be some sort of business or technical justification for embracing this model.